# stdout Won't Flush After Exception

Tags: python, stdout

I have the following Python code:

```
import sys
import traceback
fifo_in = sys.argv[1] 
while 1: 
  try:
    exec open(fifo_in)
  except:
    traceback.print_exc()
  sys.stdout.flush()
```

The first argument is a named pipe created by `mkfifo`. So the following prints '1':

```
mkfifo input
python script.py input

... in a separate terminal ...

echo "print 1" > input
```

Great, so far so good. But when I do something like `echo "foobar" > input`, the script only prints *part* of the traceback. It then pauses until I send it another command, and the output gets all mixed up:

```
echo "asdf" > input # pause here and check output
echo "print 1" > input

... in output terminal ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    exec open(fifo_in)
  File "in", line 1, in <module>
 ...PAUSES HERE...
    print 1
NameError: name 'asdf' is not defined
```

What's going on? How can I get stdout to flush fully and why is it out of order? I've tried using `traceback.format_exc` instead, then printing it by hand, but I get the same result. Calling `sys.stderr.flush` does not fix anything either. I've also tried putting a sleep in the loop to see if that helps, but nothing.

**UPDATE**

One interesting piece of behavior I am seeing: If I `ctrl+c` it, normally the program keeps running - the try/except just catches the `KeyboardInterrupt` and it keeps looping. However, if I `ctr+c` it after sending it an error, the program exits and I get the following. It's almost like it pauses inside of `print_exc`:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    traceback.print_exc()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 232, in print_exc
    print_exception(etype, value, tb, limit, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 125, in print_exception
    print_tb(tb, limit, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py", line 69, in print_tb
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 14, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 40, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py", line 132, in updatecache
    with open(fullname, 'rU') as fp:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the flush to be in your except block ?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I want it to flush no matter what path the code takes. Putting a second flush inside the except block doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It might be worth trying it out with the `flush` call in a `finally` block. I am not sure if it will work in this particular case, but I believe this type of situation is one of the reasons `finally` exists.

Comment: @bernie just tried the `finally` block. Same result. Check my update though, there seems to be some sort of mystery going on with the traceback module.

Comment: Isn't the default output file for `traceback.print_exc()` the `sys.stderr` stream rather than `sys.stdout`? Maybe flushing that instead would be more productive.

Comment: @martineau I've done that as well. It has no effect. It seems that execution is paused/stuck in linecache.py for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to look at [the stdlib code module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html)

This behavior is from using exec. Exec is for evaluating python code so "print 1" executes the python code `print 1`, where as "asdf" will raise a NameError as it does not exist in the context. `exec open(fifo_in)` is strange as it shouldn't work. The while will also eat up 100% cpu.

UPDATE: fix sleep duration
Here is a modified version of your code to try.

```
import sys
import time
import traceback
fifo_in = sys.argv[1]
try:
    fp = open(fifo_in) # will block until pipe is opened for write
except IOError:
    traceback.print_exc()
except OSError:
    traceback.print_exc()

data = None
while True:
    try:
        data = fp.read()
        try:
            exec data
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
        finally:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: Interesting, using `fp.read` fixes it, yet according to Python's documentation: "The first expression should evaluate to either a string, _an open file object_, [...]". http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt

Comment: I think it is "If it is an open file, the file is parsed until EOF and executed.". The exec is does not return waiting for EOF which never comes.

Comment: Hmm. It does run though. It just get's stuck when running traceback.print_exc. Very strange behavior. I'm marking you as correct, but this requires more investigation.

Comment: Opening the fifo on each iteration is suboptimal. But you can try `fp = open(fifo_in); try: exec fp; except: ...; finally: fp.close()`. My intuition is that the file handles get all screwed up.